# Best way to denote an error message?

Tags: discussion, markdown, information-display

I thought I remembered seeing somewhere an error message displayed like a block quote but with red coloring.  However, I cannot find any reference in the [formatting help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) page.

So what is the preferred way to include an error message in a post?  Just use a blockquote?

Comment: Are you talking about syntax highlighting in *code blocks*, or actual *blockquotes*?

Comment: I don't know what I'm talking about.  let's say I post in Superuser about a windows error and I want to put the text of that error in the question.  What is the best way to do it?  Is there anything with a color that would express "Hey, this is an error"?

Comment: On StackOverflow, most people just use `...` to denote errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought I remembered seeing somewhere an error message displayed
>   like a block quote but with red coloring

It was probably an image someone added to their post.

> I post in Superuser about a windows error and I want to put the text
>   of that error in the question. What is the best way to do it? Is there
>   anything with a color that would express "Hey, this is an error"?

Use whichever looks and reads better for the given scenario.

e.g. If within a block of text you only briefly mention the error, then use backticks within the block of text. If the error is a major part of the post, then use a quote block to separate it and make it stand out.

The quote block is coloured on all sites, although sometimes only a few shades off the background colour so doesn't stand out well.

My error is:

> failed to load second module in first stack under new condition

And backticks ` have a grey background:

The error I get is: `failed to load second module in first stack under new condition`

You can throw *italic* or **bold** into the mix but this is usually unnecessarily distracting, as long as you mark it clearly as an error, ie "This is my error:".

You can get fancy with the markdown options, such as using backticks (or  `<pre>`) within a quote:

> ```
> failed to load second module in first stack under new condition
> ```

And with italic:

> *`failed to load second module in first stack under new condition`*

You can also use a code block, but as it provides syntax highlighting you might get unwanted results. You can turn of the colour highlighting, but then it's no improvement on backticks really.

Disable syntax highlighting with `<!-- language: lang-none -->`

These are the basic ways to highlight text.

Comment: How willing do you think SE would be to add error formatting that looked exactly like the block quote except a red tint instead of yellow?  Does anyone think it's even justified?  I personally do.

Comment: Different sites have their own unique quote block colours. So could only suggest "red" for a specific site really, or a universal change somehow - perhaps an entirely new "block" altogether, for error messages specifically. If you have a good idea, with good reasons, & would be useful & used by many users, then SE and other users would certainly consider it. Just make sure it's not already asked, am sure I've seen something similar